# How do I open a view controller that is buried deep into the view hierarchy, directly from tap of a Notification alert

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uilocalnotification

Here is the problem I am facing:

I have a UITabBarController as the root view controller. It manages 4 view controllers - A,B,C,D.
C is a navigation controller that has C1 and C2 view controllers in the view hierarchy.

The objective is to open C1 view controller when the user taps on the notification in the notification center.

The problem - When the user taps on the notification, I change the tab selectedIndex to 2 (for C) which loads the view C. And in the ViewDidAppear of C, I push to C1.
Problem with this approach is that for momentarily user sees view C before being transitioned to C1 (because I am doing the transition in viewDidAppear of C). I can't do this transition in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear of C because runtime throws an error of inconsistency.

If I take an alternative approach of directly pushing C1 from my delegate than the selected tab remains the past one. If I change the selected index of the tab than it loads C again.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should use remote notifications in the event of an external push notification requires you to reposition the user within the app. This snippit should help. If not, let me know what else you need.

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    //parse notification to get intended_index = x;
    self.tab_controller.selectedIndex = intendex_index; 

    [self.tab_controller.selectedViewController.navigationController  popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];   //or push. depends on your need  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. I was able to do what you have suggested even before. but not without showing the selected controller momentarily which I don't want. Please suggest.Infact your answer takes me to only C and not C1. To go to C1 I have to push it from C, which makes it appear for a millisecond.

Comment: Ah I understand your question better now. For pushToViewController does this still occur if you set animated to no?

Comment: Yes it does occur even if animation is set to NO